# How do you create a subset of panel data with certain years in R?

Tags: r, panel-data

My panel data looks as follows:

```
structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), CountryCode = c("AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG"), Time = c("1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005"), Time.Code = c("YR1996", "YR1997", "YR1998", "YR1999", 
"YR2000", "YR2001", "YR2002", "YR2003", "YR2004", "YR2005"), 
    gdp_pc_g = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.86838029515866, 
    -2.87520316702623, 7.20796721836321), gdp_pc = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1189.78466765718, 1235.81006329565, 1200.27801321735, 
    1286.79365893927), population_g = c(4.0194777158615, 2.63650176396731, 
    1.9473438616857, 2.17042851112236, 2.97505722281038, 3.90280496415438, 
    4.4967187466326, 4.66834379545461, 4.32155951673842, 3.68269988149014
    ), savings = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), inflation = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.655238211175, 11.2714320712639, 
    10.9127735539374), unemployment = c(10.9619998931885, 10.7829999923706, 
    10.8020000457764, 10.8090000152588, 10.8059997558594, 10.8090000152588, 
    11.2569999694824, 11.1409997940063, 10.9879999160767, 11.2170000076294
    ), crime = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), health = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.08418062, 0.65096337, 0.5429256, 0.5291841
    ), health_new = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.21245611, 5.45767879, 
    3.60296822, 3.37097836), co2 = c(1180, 1100, 1040, 810, 760, 
    730, 1029.99997138977, 1220.00002861023, 1029.99997138977, 
    1549.99995231628), debt_wb = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), debt_imf = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 345.97748, 
    270.60236, 244.96669, 206.35601), qualityofgovernment = c(-1.94518780708313, 
    NA, -1.9237864613533, NA, -1.96282829840978, NA, -1.63204962015152, 
    -1.4781574010849, -1.49412107467651, -1.52730602025986), 
    migration = c(27.194, 6.129, 35.74, 85.758, -1007.135, -192.286, 
    1327.074, 388.632, -248.616, 252.185), gdp_pc_log = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.08152761818328, 7.11948195573634, 7.09030848662408, 
    7.15990886757784), gdp_pc_1996 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), gdp_pc_1996_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), unemployment_log = c(2.39443473688013, 2.3779708191924, 
    2.37973130640847, 2.38037912184574, 2.38010151282881, 2.38037912184574, 
    2.42099015466168, 2.41063197858748, 2.3968037605953, 2.41743048534325
    ), crime_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), health_new_log = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.192648145236196, 
    1.69702356932679, 1.28175801129963, 1.21520301677122), co2_log = c(7.07326971745971, 
    7.00306545878646, 6.94697599213542, 6.69703424766648, 6.63331843328038, 
    6.59304453414244, 6.93731405344676, 7.10660616117831, 6.93731405344676, 
    7.3460101791496), migration_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.194, 
    6.129, 35.74, 85.758, -1007.135), debt_imf_1996 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), debt_imf_1996_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), debt_imf_2001 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), debt_imf_2006 = c(22.984644, 
    22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 
    22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644), debt_imf_2011 = c(7.5010844, 
    7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 
    7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844), debt_imf_2016 = c(8.4372661, 
    8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 
    8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661), politics_1996 = c(-1.94518780708313, 
    -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, 
    -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, 
    -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313), 
    politics_2006 = c(-1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, 
    -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, 
    -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, 
    -1.63495093584061), politics_2016 = c(-1.55767250061035, 
    -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, 
    -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, 
    -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035), 
    politics_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.55481219291687, NA, 
    0.576213538646698, NA, 0.53717170159022), politics_2001 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), politics_2011 = c(-1.72906082868576, 
    -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, 
    -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, 
    -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576), 
    politics_t10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), debt_imf_2001_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), debt_imf_2006_log = c(3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 
    3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 
    3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627
    ), debt_imf_2011_log = c(2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 
    2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 
    2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729
    ), debt_imf_2016_log = c(2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 
    2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 
    2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292
    ), debt_imf_log = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.84637368623429, 
    5.6006504370586, 5.50112224211777, 5.32960288104705), gdp_pc_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), population_g_t5 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4.0194777158615, 2.63650176396731, 1.9473438616857, 
    2.17042851112236, 2.97505722281038), savings_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), inflation_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), unemployment_t5 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 10.9619998931885, 10.7829999923706, 10.8020000457764, 
    10.8090000152588, 10.8059997558594), crime_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), health_new_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), co2_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1180, 1100, 1040, 810, 760), debt_imf_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), qualityofgovernment_t5 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.94518780708313, NA, -1.9237864613533, 
    NA, -1.96282829840978), gdp_pc_t5_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), inflation_t5_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), unemployment_t5_log = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 2.39443473688013, 2.3779708191924, 2.37973130640847, 
    2.38037912184574, 2.38010151282881), crime_t5_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), health_new_t5_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), co2_t5_log = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 7.07326971745971, 7.00306545878646, 6.94697599213542, 
    6.69703424766648, 6.63331843328038), debt_imf_t5_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), politics = c(0.55481219291687, 
    NA, 0.576213538646698, NA, 0.53717170159022, NA, 0.867950379848478, 
    1.0218425989151, 1.00587892532349, 0.972693979740143), politics_t5_log = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.589125613643679, NA, -0.551276960171269, 
    NA, -0.621437493326265), migration_rate = c(1.59, 0.345, 
    1.934, 4.461, -50.229, -9.717, 65.242, 17.307, -10.498, 10.383
    ), migration_rate_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.59, 0.345, 
    1.934, 4.461, -50.229), inflation_new = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1.11655238211175, 1.11271432071264, 1.10912773553937
    ), inflation_new_t5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), inflation_new_t5_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Step 1 = Done

1. Now I want to create a new panel dataset such that it has every country of my previous dataset but then only with the years 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020 and 2021.
2. I want this because I would like to add a new column with the average (over the last 5 years, 2017-2021) of certain variables such as the crime variable of every country in my dataset. For simplicity, we could also use the average over the last 5 years of the population_g.

This is the new dataset which comes from step 1:

```
structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), CountryCode = c("AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG"), Time = c("1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005"), Time.Code = c("YR1996", "YR1997", "YR1998", "YR1999", 
"YR2000", "YR2001", "YR2002", "YR2003", "YR2004", "YR2005"), 
    gdp_pc_g = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.86838029515866, 
    -2.87520316702623, 7.20796721836321), gdp_pc = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1189.78466765718, 1235.81006329565, 1200.27801321735, 
    1286.79365893927), population_g = c(4.0194777158615, 2.63650176396731, 
    1.9473438616857, 2.17042851112236, 2.97505722281038, 3.90280496415438, 
    4.4967187466326, 4.66834379545461, 4.32155951673842, 3.68269988149014
    ), savings = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), inflation = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.655238211175, 11.2714320712639, 
    10.9127735539374), unemployment = c(10.9619998931885, 10.7829999923706, 
    10.8020000457764, 10.8090000152588, 10.8059997558594, 10.8090000152588, 
    11.2569999694824, 11.1409997940063, 10.9879999160767, 11.2170000076294
    ), crime = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), health = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.08418062, 0.65096337, 0.5429256, 0.5291841
    ), health_new = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.21245611, 5.45767879, 
    3.60296822, 3.37097836), co2 = c(1180, 1100, 1040, 810, 760, 
    730, 1029.99997138977, 1220.00002861023, 1029.99997138977, 
    1549.99995231628), debt_wb = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), debt_imf = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 345.97748, 
    270.60236, 244.96669, 206.35601), qualityofgovernment = c(-1.94518780708313, 
    NA, -1.9237864613533, NA, -1.96282829840978, NA, -1.63204962015152, 
    -1.4781574010849, -1.49412107467651, -1.52730602025986), 
    migration = c(27.194, 6.129, 35.74, 85.758, -1007.135, -192.286, 
    1327.074, 388.632, -248.616, 252.185), gdp_pc_log = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.08152761818328, 7.11948195573634, 7.09030848662408, 
    7.15990886757784), gdp_pc_1996 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), gdp_pc_1996_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), unemployment_log = c(2.39443473688013, 2.3779708191924, 
    2.37973130640847, 2.38037912184574, 2.38010151282881, 2.38037912184574, 
    2.42099015466168, 2.41063197858748, 2.3968037605953, 2.41743048534325
    ), crime_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), health_new_log = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.192648145236196, 
    1.69702356932679, 1.28175801129963, 1.21520301677122), co2_log = c(7.07326971745971, 
    7.00306545878646, 6.94697599213542, 6.69703424766648, 6.63331843328038, 
    6.59304453414244, 6.93731405344676, 7.10660616117831, 6.93731405344676, 
    7.3460101791496), migration_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.194, 
    6.129, 35.74, 85.758, -1007.135), debt_imf_1996 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), debt_imf_1996_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), debt_imf_2001 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), debt_imf_2006 = c(22.984644, 
    22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644, 
    22.984644, 22.984644, 22.984644), debt_imf_2011 = c(7.5010844, 
    7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844, 
    7.5010844, 7.5010844, 7.5010844), debt_imf_2016 = c(8.4372661, 
    8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661, 
    8.4372661, 8.4372661, 8.4372661), politics_1996 = c(-1.94518780708313, 
    -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, 
    -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, 
    -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313, -1.94518780708313), 
    politics_2006 = c(-1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, 
    -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, 
    -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, -1.63495093584061, 
    -1.63495093584061), politics_2016 = c(-1.55767250061035, 
    -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, 
    -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, 
    -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035, -1.55767250061035), 
    politics_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.55481219291687, NA, 
    0.576213538646698, NA, 0.53717170159022), politics_2001 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), politics_2011 = c(-1.72906082868576, 
    -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, 
    -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, 
    -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576, -1.72906082868576), 
    politics_t10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), debt_imf_2001_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), debt_imf_2006_log = c(3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 
    3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 
    3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627, 3.13482634077627
    ), debt_imf_2011_log = c(2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 
    2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 
    2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729, 2.01504759675729
    ), debt_imf_2016_log = c(2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 
    2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 
    2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292, 2.13265833433292
    ), debt_imf_log = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.84637368623429, 
    5.6006504370586, 5.50112224211777, 5.32960288104705), gdp_pc_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), population_g_t5 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4.0194777158615, 2.63650176396731, 1.9473438616857, 
    2.17042851112236, 2.97505722281038), savings_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), inflation_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), unemployment_t5 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 10.9619998931885, 10.7829999923706, 10.8020000457764, 
    10.8090000152588, 10.8059997558594), crime_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), health_new_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), co2_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1180, 1100, 1040, 810, 760), debt_imf_t5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), qualityofgovernment_t5 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.94518780708313, NA, -1.9237864613533, 
    NA, -1.96282829840978), gdp_pc_t5_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), inflation_t5_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), unemployment_t5_log = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 2.39443473688013, 2.3779708191924, 2.37973130640847, 
    2.38037912184574, 2.38010151282881), crime_t5_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), health_new_t5_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), co2_t5_log = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 7.07326971745971, 7.00306545878646, 6.94697599213542, 
    6.69703424766648, 6.63331843328038), debt_imf_t5_log = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), politics = c(0.55481219291687, 
    NA, 0.576213538646698, NA, 0.53717170159022, NA, 0.867950379848478, 
    1.0218425989151, 1.00587892532349, 0.972693979740143), politics_t5_log = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.589125613643679, NA, -0.551276960171269, 
    NA, -0.621437493326265), migration_rate = c(1.59, 0.345, 
    1.934, 4.461, -50.229, -9.717, 65.242, 17.307, -10.498, 10.383
    ), migration_rate_t5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.59, 0.345, 
    1.934, 4.461, -50.229), inflation_new = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1.11655238211175, 1.11271432071264, 1.10912773553937
    ), inflation_new_t5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), inflation_new_t5_log = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You say you want the average over the last 5y of certain variables. Is that a rolling average (in which case it needs to be done before filtering), or is that column going to be invariant for each country? It helps to see your expected output. Also, your desired years are not present in your data, and `crime` is all `NA`. The premise of filtering is clear (`base::subset(data, Time >= 2017 & Time <= 2021)` or `dplyr::filter(data, between(Time, 2017, 2021))`), then see [summarize by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272).

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  type_convert() %>% 
  filter(between(Time, 2017, 2021))
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I would like to take the average of certain variables of this new column. I have added the new dataset in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach:
In your example data, after filtering no data will be left, therefore we can't calculate the average.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(grepl(paste(2017:2021, collapse = "|"), Time)) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

Example for year 2003 to 2005:

```
df %>% 
  filter(grepl(paste(2003:2005, collapse = "|"), Time)) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(Time, Country) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(gdp_pc_g, gdp_pc), ~mean(.), .names = "mean_{col}"))
```

```
   Time Country     mean_gdp_pc_g mean_gdp_pc
  <int> <chr>               <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2003 Afghanistan          3.87       1236.
2  2004 Afghanistan         -2.88       1200.
3  2005 Afghanistan          7.21       1287.
```